# Count active merchants according to contract creation date and termination date for each day from 2017

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I would like to count my active partners (merchants) for each day from 2017-01-01

I have a postgresql datawarehouse where
I have a source table called sources like this:

| merchantid | contract_date | termination_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-05-28 | 2021-05-28 |
| 2 | 2018-05-27 | 2022-05-27 |
| 3 | 2018-16-14 | NULL |
| 4 | 2020-11-14 | NULL |
| 5 | 2021-03-15 | NULL |
| 6 | 2022-01-04 | NULL |

And I have a goal table called historical_active_merchants table like this:

| date | num_of_merchants |
| --- | --- |
| ... |  |
| ... |  |
| 2021-05-26 |  |
| 2021-05-27 |  |
| 2021-05-27 |  |
| 2021-05-27 |  |
| 2021-05-27 |  |
| 2021-05-27 |  |
| ... |  |
| ... |  |
| ... |  |

... are days before and after from 2017-01-01 until now

My logic how it would be nice to work:

```
UPDATE historical_active_merchants SET num_of_merchants=num_of_merchants+1 
WHERE (sources.contract_date <= historical_active_merchants.date
AND sources.termination_date > historical_active_merchants.date)
OR (sources.contract_date <= historical_active_merchants.date
AND sources.termination_date is null)
```

Is it possible without loops?
Or is there a solution by using loop?

I just can't list here all the attepmts I've tried already...

I appreciate any tips and solutions and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update historical_active_merchants based on a select that counts the merchants.

```
update historical_active_merchants H
set num_of_merchants = count_merchants
from (
  select H.date, count(S.merchantid) as count_merchants
  from historical_active_merchants H
  left join sources S on H.date >= S.contract_date 
    and (S.termination_date is null or H.date <= S.termination_date)
  group by H.date
) X
where H.date = X.date;
```

(the subquery is needed because of the group by)

Comment: You are amazing, thank you!!!
I am very happy of this solution and I learned a nice way of counting data according to other tables data!

only a distinct was missing from the count function :)

Comment: You're welcome! I might be wrong but the distinct is not really needed if sources doesn't contain duplicate values of merchantid. It doesn't hurt to add it of course (maybe just a small performance impact, IDK).

Comment: In my case the sources table is containing duplicates :)
Overall, thanks once more and aprichiate!